# DJ Compiler will not open some files

Tags: java

I upgraded to WIN 10 about 6 months ago and since then i have problems opening files in DJ Compiler. Some open up just fine and i can work on them and save them as normal, while others that used to open ok now will not. When trying to open i get an error message

> File access error, or file not exists. Check and try again! Possible reasons: file xxxxx.class is corrupted or the output folder is read only.

even though the output folder is set the same as the for the files that open ok.

ANy suggestions please? Pulling my hair out here!

regards

Comment: Did you install DJ *before* your Win10 upgrade? If so, try reinstalling

Comment: yes i have tried installing and reinstalling several times thanks